# Unexpected token ) in, while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

I am trying to create a validation using  express-validation but I am having a syntax error in my html page

I would appreciate If anyone can give me a clue on the issue I encounter.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) in /Users/johnmichaelquintero/Projects/rateme/views/user/signup.ejs while compiling ejs. If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint: https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
```

signup.ejs

```html
<% if(hasErrors) {%>
                <% for(var i=0; i < messages.length; i++) {%>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <a href="" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">
                            &time;
                        </a>  
                    </div>
                    <%= messages[i] =%>
                <% } %>
            <% } %>
```

user.js:

```js
app.get('/signup', (req, res) => {
        var errors = req.flash('error'); //to get the error message
        console.log(errors);
        res.render('user/signup', {title: 'Signup || RateMe', messages: errors, hasErrors: errors.Length > 0});
    });
```

Comment: I've not used EJS in forever but this line `<%= messages[i] =%>` looks incorrect - you don't need the `=` to close, do you? Seems like it may be interpreting it as an assignment operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the `=%>` after `messages[i]`. There should not be an equal sign there.

This should work:

```
<% if(hasErrors) {%>
                <% for(var i=0; i < messages.length; i++) {%>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <a href="" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">
                            &time;
                        </a>  
                    </div>
                    <%= messages[i] %>
                <% } %>
            <% } %>
```